# Python how to handle web service security when storing data into 'shelve' module?

Tags: python, web-services, security, request, shelve

I'm very new to python and am looking at [shelve module to store data persistently](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) for a simple web service exposed to the internet. I see the following warning on the shelve's documentation page and am interested if there's some additional scrubbing or verification I need to do if i'm to store parameters received with web requests on the shelve.

> Warning Because the shelve module is backed by pickle,
>   it is insecure to load a shelf from an untrusted source. Like with pickle,
>   loading a shelf can execute arbitrary code.

**Do I need to do additional verification/scrubbing or checks if I'm to store data into shelve using code below?** Is there a risk of some executable code being passed in this way?

```
@app.route('/test/login/')
def login():
    username = request.args.get('username')
    password = request.args.get('password')
    print 'username: '+username + ' password: ' + password

    shelf = shelve.open('testfile')
    shelf['username'] = username
    shelf['password'] = password

    value1 = shelf['username']
    print 'restored: '+ value1

    shelf.close()
    #etc


    return
```

Comment: Although that warning doesn't apply to your use case, the second point of the [restrictions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html#restrictions) section in the documentation does: _„The shelve module does not support concurrent read/write access to shelved objects.”_ In general you can't be sure only one user at a given time is triggering that code, so you better use a database that allows concurrent access.

Answer (score 2):

The warning only applies if you were to try and interpret *user supplied data* as a pickle.

Storing data *in* the shelve never lets you do this; `username` and `password` are never interpreted by the `shelve` module as pickle data when stored. The `shelve` module always creates a pickle record of any data stored, loading the value back when accessing the key again for reading. Since your user data is thus *wrapped in a pickle* it is never itself interpreted as such.

You'd have to take user-supplied data and try to pass this to `pickle.loads()` or have `shelve` open the user data as a shelve file for this to happen. The code you posted is not vulnerable to this problem.